# Java Matcher not working

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have the function:

```
Boolean rhyme(String words) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("...");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(words);
  matcher.matches();
  return matcher.group(1).equals(matcher.group(2));
}
```

where `String words` contains two words separated by a `\t` like: `read\tdead`.
The function is supposed to check to see if the last three letters of each word are equal, and if so returns `true`, otherwise return `false`.

I can't change any of the code, I'm just supposed to create the regex expression so that this functions works.

My current expression is `(.{3}?)(?=[\t])|(.{3}$)` and when I plug this into [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tP7qE7/27) it seems to work. When I use that expression in the function, I get an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` error. Can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong, and remember, I can't change any of the code except for the pattern expression.

Comment: Seeing the actual problematic code would be helpful. Did you escape the '\' in your regex?

Comment: @JamieBisotti Java will register the string as `read    dead` so i won't have to escape the '\'. Plus I've tried that anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is flawed unfortunately.  More needs to be changed to make this work, because if there is no match (ie, words don't end with the same 3 letters) then `matcher.matches()` will return `false`.  Continuing with the next statement will then always throw an exception as there was no match, and therefore there are no groups to access.

Working example (with tweaked regex):

```
boolean rhyme(String words) {
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(.{3})(?=[\\t]).*(.{3}$)");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(words);

   return matcher.matches() && matcher.group(1).equals(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Comment: The constraints for the `words` is `7 ≤ words.length ≤ 1000`

Comment: So each words will always have 3 or more letters

Comment: Your expression works perfectly. could you explain how mine doesn't work compared to yours?